# Can I run multiple node.js files

Tags: node.js

I have a server.js file which runs my server and displays html files. In a client side javascript file I would like to make an ajax request to a separate server side js file which pulls in data from an API. Is this possible? or is there a better solution when working in a node environment.

Comment: Are you trying to have two separate APIs?  Why not the make that second API exposed via the first script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run multiple node.js files on a same server. Launching each with `node my_file.js`.

---

And yes, there is a better option to reach desired effect, instead of launching multiple servers. I would even discourage you launching second server, unless you intentionally want it to be fully independent entity.

Solution is called routing, for instance you want to serve two functionalities with Node.js:

1. `http://my-app.com/`
2. `http://my-app.com/api/users`

As I understand you know how to implement them, now you just need a *router* to unite them.

There are [many routers available](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/router), with great examples and documentation.

Let us consider you have chosen *Express*, then following [this guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) your main (starting point) JS file will have simple instructions telling what JS file serves what part of your website:

```
app.get('/', mySite.index);
app.all('/api/*', myApi.index);
```

Notice: that is incomplete code, refer to [ExpressJS documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), or other router you decide to use.
ExpressJS is a rich framework, if you need only router, you might want to find something simpler.

Comment: Hey thanks, I am using express, I was just thinking from a PHP apache server perspective. This is a great solution though

Comment: @wazzaday yes the Apache PHP combo is slightly different. Apache is in the role of router there, as well as PHP interpreter. With Node.js you have command `node` which is interpreter, and have to worry about the role of *router* yourself :) That is good though, back to the origins of computers - more control = more possibilities.